# Blackberry runtime store class cast exception

Tags: blackberry, java-me

The following line in my BLackBerry app causes no errors when run with JRE 7 but it gives a ClassCastException otherwise. Does anyone have an idea about what can be wrong?

```
DataBuffer databuffer = 
    (DataBuffer) RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore().get(AppMain.databufferID);
```

Comment: When you say "JRE 7" do you mean BlackBerry SDK 7.0?  Are you compiling your app with SDK 7.0 and expecting it to work on earlier versions of BlackBerry OS?  Generally, you want to build with the SDK for the earliest version of BBOS you want to support. OS 5 would be a good choice.

Comment: I go to run configurations I choose JRE 6. When I do that the old simulator starts up so I assume that ifit runs there it's good to go for OS 6 as well ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: Anyways actually there was a problem  with the package names that was very difficult to catch which was the cause of the error sorry about this